# LinkedIn API permissions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having following permissions scope in my LinkedIn API [image: List of Permissions]

But when I sign in using LinkedIn it only ask for these many permission.[image: Asked by my application]

Can someone tell me what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Since I was using simpleauth, I just have to add these permissions in my secrets.py file under

```
AUTH_CONFIG{ 
    'linkedin2': (LINKEDIN_KEY, LINKEDIN_SECRET, 'r_emailaddress'),}
```

And it worked.